# Network Manager icon disapear 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, icons, wireless-access-point

After installing `hostapd` (Ubuntu 14.04) Network Manager icon disappears. Even after removing `hostapd`, still Network Manager icon is not appearing.

- During boot up:

  > Waiting up to 60 seconds to start network configuration
- and after that another message:

  > booting up without network configuration

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does it give any error if you run `nm-applet` from terminal?

Comment: ** (nm-applet:11914): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files           

(nm-applet:11914): nm-applet-WARNING **: Error connecting to ModemManager: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Cannot launch daemon, file not found or permissions invalid

Comment: What about `sudo service networking restart`?

Comment: I tried that getting "stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start"

Comment: Hi everyone, the problem was a bad bridge setting under the /etc/ directory... As the bridge setting was incorrect, the network service was not loading correctly. So, "sudo service networking restart" fails for that matter as well...

Answer (score 2):

A bug with Network Manager obviously can be solved this way:

First you need anyway purge `hostapd` together with configuration:

```
sudo apt-get purge hostapd
```

Then try to reinstall `network-manager`, and this way your configuration of `network-manager` will be saved:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall -fmu network-manager
```

<sub>where `-f` is *fix-broken*, `-m` is *fix-missing* and `-u` is *show upgraded*</sub>

```
sudo reboot
```

**OR completely** purge `hostapd` & `network-manager` *together with their configurations and again freshly install* `network-manager` by single command:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y hostapd && sudo apt-get purge -y network-manager && sudo apt-get install network-manager && sudo reboot
```

For a chance to have `hostapd` installed my opinion you need to go step-by-step this guide:
[WifiDocs / MasterMode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode)

Then, if success you can begin stepping second guide to setup your wifi from there:
[Using `hostapd` on Ubuntu to create a wifi access point](http://cberner.com/2013/02/03/using-hostapd-on-ubuntu-to-create-a-wifi-access-point/)

#### Cited the part `5.Troubleshooting` from second guide:

> If you have network-manager configured to use your wifi card, you
>   should disable auto-connect for all the wireless connections.
>   Otherwise, it may interfere with `hostapd`. If some frequencies are
>   disabled, make sure your driver is set to use the right regulatory
>   domain. You can see the current one with:
>
> ```
> iw reg get
> ```
>
> If it says `country 00`, you need to set it manually, in
>   `/etc/default/crda`. To set it manually you need (at least for some
>   cards) to have `cfg80211` and `mac80211` installed as kernel modules. You
>   can check if they’re installed as modules by using:
>
> ```
> zcat /proc/config.gz
> ```
>
> Look for `CONFIG_CFG80211=m`, if it says “=y” then it’s compiled into
>   the kernel, and you’ll need to re-install your kernel. If you’re using
>   an Atheros card, you may also need to set the region in the driver. Do
>   this by adding “cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=US” to `/etc/modules`

Last sentence is about your country code sure.

Comment: Does this also purges all the settings such as custom bridges? The problem was originated because of an incorrect bridge configuration that prevented the networking service to restart... Please let me know if your approach would remove any bridge settings and I would grant you the bounty points.

Comment: you're right, here should be some clarification, about first case which above phrase "OR completely" that won't remove `network-manager`  configuration, about second case which below them and this way "yes, configuration of network-manager will be removed". `hostapd` configuration will be purged anyway. Should I add this to the answer?

Comment: added little update