# network manager icon on 16.04 is not showing

Tags: networking, 16.04

After installing 16.04 network manager icon no longer shows. Cannot start vpn. Wired connections details show but no options.

Comment: For me, the network manager applet is shown ok, but there isn't any list of networks. The wifi automatically connects to the first available instead of giving me a choice.

Answer (score 3):

Below commands help me (this command disable/enable [network-manager applet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#NM-applet_Overview)) :

```
$ nm-applet --disable
$ nm-applet --enable
```

Comment: Maybe you can add comments to describe what the commands do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the same behave, the wireless device connects to first available!
The only way found to see which one is, by command line:

```
:~]$ iwconfig
```

:(

Comment: Ok, It can helps for now the command nmcli like following:

`code` ~]$ nmcli dev wifi list `code`

Comment: Yo can get more info from this [link]http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80126/how-to-connect-to-internet-using-nmcli

Comment: basically: `code`nmcli con up id  ' GRANDEZZA 1'    -> the name is the alias you have/had configured on `code`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y hostapd && sudo apt-get purge -y network-manager && sudo apt-get install network-manager && sudo reboot
```

As seen in: [Network Manager icon disapear 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512519/network-manager-icon-disapear-14-04?rq=1)